# What permission to use when sharing on Facebook using Unity

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk, publish-actions

I share screenshots on Facebook from my android app (developed on Unity)
and it used to work perfect, but I guess Facebook changed their policy and I have no Idea what permissions I need to use in order to continue sharing a texture on Facebook.

That's how I log in:

```
   var permissions = new List<string>() {"publish_actions"};
   FB.LogInWithPublishPermissions(permissions);
```

By using  `CurrentAccessToken.Permissions` I receive on debugger: `Permissions: public_profile` (which means the user didn't get the publish_actions permission).

And when I try to share the pic on Facebook by-

`FB.API("me/photos", HttpMethod.POST, APICallback, wwwForm);`
I receive `403 forbidden`.

I read that `publish_actions` got removed, so how can I share a screenshot now?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah there is no need for publishing permission anymore. How about trying 
FB.ShareLink. this is what I use now. Facebook has a new way of sharing you can't do it frictionless anymore. With this, a popup keeps appearing related to posting.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/unity/reference/current/FB.ShareLink